# Подмена текста php скриптом для AMP версии сайта

Tags: php, dle, amp

Есть два сайта на Dle,которые используют одну базу данных. Один сайт является основной "мордой" сайт, другой генерирует AMP страницы.

Как известно, AMP использует специальные теги, поэтому возникает проблема при добавлении изображений. В результате того, что используется одна база, нет возможности вставлять отдельные картинки с тегами для AMP версии.

Вижу решение этой проблемы в php скрипте, который бы на лету менял теги img на amp-img, но знаний для его написания маловато. Или возможно кто то видит другое решение этой проблемы?

Поделитесь советом или готовым решением.

Answer (score 1):

### Не храните тэги в базе!

Классический [MVC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller) решает данную проблему на раз.

Представление модели в JSON

```json
{
    "name"     : "Name 1",
    "imageUrl" : "/img/path/123.png" 
}
```

Вид для картинки для обычного сайта ([mustache](https://mustache.github.io/))

```html
<img src="{{imageUrl}}" alt="{{name}}" />
```

Вид для AMP

```html
<amp-img src="{{imageUrl}}" alt="{{name}}"></amp-img>
```

А в контроллере вы сможете решить какой вид рендерить.

**PS:**

> В результате того, что используется одна база, нет возможности вставлять отдельные картинки с тегами для AMP версии.

Совершенно непонятное высказывание. *Архетектурно ужасно* и **надо пользовать MVC** но:

1. Добавить вторую колонку.
2. Добавить вторую таблицу, если используется PostgreSQL можно добавить таблицы с наследованием.
3. Манипулировать входяшие данные через тригеры.
4. Создать Views/Stored procedures которые будут переформатировать те же данные для разных ситуаций.

Ни чем из списка я бы не пользовался, для решения вашей проблемы, просто хотел показать что вариантов куча.